# How is this group theoretic construct called?

Tags: reference-request, gr.group-theory, finite-groups, group-cohomology

Let $G$ be a finite group, $S\subset G$ a generating set, $|g| = |g|_S = $ word length with respect to $S$. Define the "defect" of $g,h$ to be

$$\psi(g,h) = |g|+|h|-|gh|$$

Then $\psi:G\times G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}$ is a $2$-cocycle and satisfies the normalizing condition $\psi(g,1) = \psi(1,g) = 0$.

Construct a group $\mathbb{Z} \times G$ by defining:

$$(a,g)\oplus(b,h) := (a+b+\psi(g,h), gh)$$

This is associative, since $\psi$ is a 2-cocycle. Furthermore, define a norm on $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ by setting:
$$|(a,g)| := |a|+|g|$$
Then this norm is subadditive:
$$|x \oplus y| \le |x| + |y|$$
If we restrict this norm on $\mathbb{N}_0 \times G$ then it is additive.
Using this norm one can define a metric on $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ by setting:
$$d(x,y):= \max\{ |x^{-1} \oplus y|,|y^{-1} \oplus x|\}$$
Furthermore, the group $G$ operates on $\mathbb{Z} \times G$ by setting:
$$g \cdot (a,h) := (a+\psi(g,h),gh) = (0,g)\oplus(a,h)$$
This group acts isometrically on $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ as we have:
$$d(g\cdot x, g\cdot y) = d(x,y)$$

I came across this construction by trying to mimic "elementary addition and the carrying process", but I do not know how this construction is called and what further properties it has. Any hint would be very nice!

Thanks for your help!

**Edit 23.05.2019**:
**Is there a description of finite index subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\times G$ in terms of subgroups of $G$ and $\mathbb{Z}$?**

By observation of Ashot Minasyan, this group is isomorphic as groups to $\mathbb{Z} \times G=$ the direct product, via:

$$\beta : \mathbb{Z} \times G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times_S G: (a,g) \mapsto (a-|g|,g)$$

It is to me unclear however, if this group homomorphism is an isometry of metric spaces?

Comment: If you divide this quantity by 2, it becomes **Gromov product**, denoted $(g,h)_e$, which is defined for general metric spaces, not just for Cayley graphs.

Comment: @Misha: Thanks for your comment. Which quantity do you mean?

Comment: $\psi(g,h)$ is twice the Gromov product.

Comment: @Misha: I don't think they are the same, although maybe related.

Comment: Sorry, it is $\psi(g,h^{-1})$, and assuming symmetric generating set so that $|h|=|h^{-1}|$.

Comment: Since your $2$-cocycle is defined as the coboundary of the $1$-cochain $g \mapsto |g|$, the group that you get is the genuine direct product $\mathbb{Z} \times G$. In fact, the map $g \mapsto (|g|,g)$ defines an embedding of $G$ into your construction, which commutes with the natural copy of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ashotminasyan: I don't understand how this is a group homomorphism?

Comment: @orgesleka: Sorry, it should be $g \mapsto (-|g|,g)$.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan: Ok, I see that this defines an embedding from $G$ to $\mathbb{Z}\times_S G$ and this gives a bijection $\beta: \mathbb{Z} \times_S G \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \times G, (a,g) \mapsto (a-|g|,g)$. But is this a homomorphism of groups? I don't see that.

Comment: @orgesleka: your map $\beta$ should go in the opposite direction, from the genuine direct product to your construction. The formula is the same, and it is a group isomorphism, as you can check directly.

Comment: @AshotMinasyan: Ok thanks! That makes sense!